# Convert dates with time-offset as defined in RFC 3339 to timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I’m trying to compare a given date with the current, but I have problems, if I am using a date formatted as described in RFC 3339 using a time-offset.

E.g. the given time string is "2015-10-16T13:00:00Z+02:00" and I want to get the difference:

```
$difference = strtotime("2015-10-16T13:00:00Z+02:00") - time();
```

But `$difference` is set to the same as if I’m using "2015-10-16T13:00:00Z".

I have also set the default timezone to "UTC" using `date_default_timezone_set` but this changes nothing.

If I am using a time string without the closing "Z" (e.g. "2015-10-16T13:00:00") all works fine.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: So you need a output of `2015-10-16T15:00:00`  ??

Comment: `Z+02:00` is invalid.  It would either be `Z` or it would be `+02:00` - not both.  (`Z` means `+00:00`)

Comment: @MattJohnson: Sorry for the late response, but your comment answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Posted as answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the input.  `Z+02:00` is invalid.

ISO8601 / RFC3339 allow *either* `Z` or `+02:00` - not both.  (`Z` means `+00:00`)